# How to avoid list.erase calling the destructor

Tags: c++, list, destructor, erase

I'm trying to return a value inside a list and then remove it from the list, but without erasing its content. But when I call `list.erase`, this function calls the item's destructor. So the content of `temp` after the item is erased is destroyed too. How can I keep the content of `temp`?

```
Vertice *temp = NULL;

//Remove da lista o vértice escolhido para iniciar a busca.
for (list<Vertice>::iterator it = lista.begin(); it != lista.end(); it++) {
    if (it->getId() == (v)) {
        temp = &*it;
        lista.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The singular of vertices is "vertex".

Comment: @Lightness In English yes, but not in Portuguese which appears to be the predominant language of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of `unique_ptr<Vertice>`, and the `swap` method to move ownership of the object to another pointer before calling `erase`.

Comment: Thank you! But first I have to study `unique_ptr` to learn how to use it. It seams too powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy the value rather than taking a pointer to it before erasing.

```
Vertice temp;

temp = *it;
```

You can improve this by using `std::optional<Vertice>` to avoid constructing an empty `Vertice` first.